# Derive a particular expression for binomial deviance from Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: machine-learning, binomial-distribution, loss-functions

When discussing AdaBoost, authors in ESL mention that exponential loss minimizer also minimizes binomial deviance. I have trouble deriving this connection. In particular, the book states:

> Another loss criterion with the same population minimizer is the binomial negative log-likelihood or deviance (also known as cross-entropy), interpreting f as the logit transform. Let
>   $$
> p(x) = Pr(Y=1|x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-2f(x)}}
> $$
>   and define 
>   $$
> {Y}'= (Y + 1)/2 ∈ \{0, 1\}. 
> $$
>   Then the binomial log-likelihood loss function is:
>   $$
> l(Y, p(x)) = {Y}' log(p(x)) + (1 - {Y}') log(1 - p(x)),
> $$
>   or equivalently the deviance is
>   $$
> -l(Y, f(x)) = log(1 + e^{-2Yf(x))})
> $$

I don't understand how the last expression was obtained. In another thread here I saw an expression I can derive myself:
$$
yP - log (1 + e^{P}),
$$
but it doesn't look similar to the expression in the book. So the question is, how that equation for the deviance was obtained?

Answer (score 4):

If we have a classifier which, for a given x, tells us the probability that $y=1$ and the probability that $y=-1$, using a function $f(x)$ such that the probability that $y=1$ is given by $\frac{1}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}$ and the probability that $y=-1$ is thus given by $1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}=\frac{e^{-2f(x)}}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}$, then for a specific value of x, the expected negative log likelihood is given by:

$P(y=1|x)\cdot - \ln \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}\right) + P(y=-1|x)\cdot - \ln\left(\frac{e^{-2f(x)}}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}\right)$

A bit of rearranging and and noting that $P(y=1|x)+P(y=-1|x)=1$ yields:
$\ln(1+e^{-2f(x)})+2\cdot P(y=-1|x)f(x)$

To find the $f(x)$ which maximises this, we differentiate wrt f(x) as were it a constant, and find:

$-2\frac{e^{-2f(x)}}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}+2P(y=-1|x)=-2\frac{e^{-2f(x)}}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}+2(1-P(y=1|x))$

which equals zero when $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left[\frac{P(y=1|x)}{1-P(y=1|X)}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left[\frac{P(y=1|x)}{P(y=-1|X)}\right]$

This is the same $f(x)$ which minimises the expected exponential loss for any given x.

My (possibly flawed) understanding of this (in my view quite confusing) paragraph in ESL is that if we are using a function $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ as a classifier for a variable $y \in \{-1,1\}$, we could proceed simply by minimising exponential loss and the fact that $\frac{1}{2}\ln\left[\frac{P(y=1|x)}{P(y=-1|X)}\right]$ minimises the expected loss for any given x suggests that one can interpret the output of $f(x)$ to mean that $\hat{y}=1$ if $f(x)>0$ and $\hat{y}=-1$ if $f(x)<0$. This seems like a fairly sensible way to interpret $f(x)$ and thus maybe exponential loss is a sensible/meaningful type of loss.

Alternately, we could interpret $f(x)$ straight off the bat and somewhat arbitrarily claim that its meaning is that the probability that y=1 is given by $\frac{1}{1+e^{-2f(x)}}$. Then, if we seek to find $f(x)$ so as to maximise the expected log-likelihood, we find the expected $f(x)$ is the same as the one which minimises the exponential loss condition.

Just because the two interpretations of $f(x)$ and their corresponding loss functions lead to the same expected $f(x)$ given an underlying conditional distribution $P(y|x)$ does not mean that one would expect these two losses to yield the same classifiers given a real data set (i.e. a sample from said distribution)

Answer (score 2):

In short, I think the equivalence is because of the change of notation and parametrization for $P(f)$. Below is my discussion.

When $y \in \{0, 1\}$, the negative binomial log-likelihood has this form:
$$\tag{1}-[ylog(P)+(1-y)log(1-P)]$$, where
$$P(f) = \frac{e^{f}}{1+e^{f}}$$
Then we can rewrite the original $(1)$ to obtain your last expression:
$$-[ylog(\frac{e^{f}}{1+e^{f}}) + (1-y)log(1-\frac{e^{f}}{1+e^{f}})]$$ $$= -y[log(e^{f})-log({1+e^{f}})] - (1-y)log(\frac{1}{1+e^{f}})$$
$$= -y[f-log({1+e^{f}})] - (1-y)[-log(1+e^{f})]$$
$$= -yf+ylog({1+e^{f}}) +log(1+e^{f}) - ylog(1+e^{f})$$
$$= -yf + log(1+e^{f})$$
We can also denote all $y$ above by $y_{left}$ and parametrize above $P(f)$ by $$\tag{2}P=\frac{e^{f_{new}}}{e^{f_{new}}+e^{-f_{new}}}$$, which I think actually it just parameterize original $f$ by $2f_{new}$. I borrowed 'parametrize' from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2752.pdf), section 3.1 page 5.

In your question, the equivalence mentioned by the book is:
$$\tag{3}-[yf - log(1+e^{f})] \equiv log(1+e^{-2yf})$$
which I think it actually is:
$$\tag{*}-[y_{left}f - log(1+e^{f})] \equiv log(1+e^{-2y_{right}f_{new}})$$

, where $y_{left} \in \{0, 1\}$, and $y_{right} \in \{-1, 1\}$.
The relationship between $y_{left}$ and $y_{right}$ is that $$\tag{4}y_{left} = \frac{y_{right}+1}{2}$$ and $(4)$ can be checked by plugging 0 for $y_{left}$ and -1 for $y_{right}$, or 1 for both $y_{left}$ and $y_{right}$. Other than these two pairs, the equality fails.

We can substitute P and $y$, which has been renamed by $y_{left}$ earlier, of $(1)$ by the $(2)$ and $(4)$, then $(1)$ becomes
$$-\frac{y_{right}+1}{2}log(\frac{e^{2f_{new}}}{1+e^{2f_{new}}})-(1-\frac{y_{right}+1}{2})log(\frac{1}{1+e^{2f_{new}}})$$
$$= -\frac{y_{right}+1}{2}[2f_{new}-log(1+e^{2f_{new}})]+\frac{1-y_{right}}{2}log(1+e^{2f_{new}})$$
$$= -(y_{right}+1)f_{new}+\frac{y_{right}+1}{2}log(1+e^{2f_{new}})+\frac{1-y_{right}}{2}log(1+e^{2f_{new}})$$
$$= -(y_{right}+1)f_{new}+log(1+e^{2f_{new}})$$
$$\equiv log(1+e^{-2y_{right}f_{new}})$$
The last equivalance here is because that it is $log(1+e^{2f_{new}})$ when $y_{right}=-1$ and $-2f_{new}+log(1+e^{2f_{new}}) = -log(\frac{e^{2f_{new}}}{1+e^{2f_{new}}}) = -log(\frac{1}{1+e^{-2f_{new}}}) = log(1+e^{-2f_{new}})$ when $y_{right}=1$. Hence these two scenarios can be summarized by $log(1+e^{-2y_{right}f_{new}})$ of which $y_{new} \in \{-1, 1\}$

Therefore in my opinion, the above 'equivalence' $(3)$ doesn't mean that two formulas really equals to each other everywhere of $y$. It only holds when $y$ (or $y_{left}) = 0$ and $y_{right} = -1$, or $y_{left} = 1$ and $y_{right} = 1$. And the $f$ is parametrized by $2f_{new}$.

In sum, if you use $y$ (or $y_{left}$) and $f$, you will have the the left side of $(*)$ from $(1)$. If you use $y_{right}$ and $f_{new}$, you will get the right side of $(*)$ from $(1)$. So they are equivalent. (I believe there is more concise explanation than above.)

I think the parametrization is because that the logistic function $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ monotonically maps real value of $x$ from $(-\infty, \infty)$ to $(0,1)$, so a coefficient of $2$ ahead of $x$ doesn't change this mapping purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just algebra.

$$
\begin{aligned}
-l &= -y' \ln \frac{1}{1+e^{-2f}}-(1-y')\ln(1- \frac{e^{-2f}}{1+e^{-2f}}) \\
 &= \ln \left[ (1+e^{-2f})^{y'} (1+e^{2f})^{1-y'} \right] \\
 &= \ln (1+e^{-2yf})
\end{aligned}
$$

You can verify the last equal sign by plugging in $Y=1$ and $Y=-1$ respectively.